# How to turn on antialiasing in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, antialiasing, realitykit

Is there a way to turn on antialiasing in RealityKit? Or is it only available in SceneKit? In SceneKit you can use [antialiasingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524085-antialiasingmode) and [isJitteringEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524026-isjitteringenabled)
Are there any alternatives in RealityKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `multisampling` nor `jittering` options are available in RealityKit 2.0 at the moment.